# I tried mapping a React state but it is not returning data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, react-state

I am a beginner in React and today I stumbled upon a problem, perhaps I could use some help.

The Home component needs to display a card with data brought in from an API.

This is what I did:

```
<div>
            {
                allRecipes?.map((e) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <Link to={"/home" + e.id}>
                                <Card title={e.title}/>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
```

I was expecting it to render a Card with in this case for brevity the title of a cooking recipe, this did not work and it's not being rendered.

I will share a link source of my GitHub repo: [Click here](https://github.com/andresehb/recipe_browser)

Comment: Quick suggestion: Don't push `node_modules` in Github there is no need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the usage of the Link component.

Try this:

1. Make sure to import the Link component and provide a valid URL path for the to prop.
2. Include a unique key prop to the outer div element. The key prop helps to efficiently update and manage the list of elements. You can use a unique identifier like the id property of each recipe as the key value.

   ```
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    // ...

   <div>
   {
     allRecipes?.map((recipe) => (
       <div key={recipe.id}> {/* Added a unique "key" prop */}
          <Link to={"/home/" + recipe.id}> {/* Adjusted the link URL */}
              <Card title={recipe.title} /> 
          </Link>
      </div>
   ))
   }
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A small correction might work for you.

```html
<div>
{
    allRecipes?.map((e) =>  (
            <div>
                <Link to={"/home" + e.id}>
                    <Card title={e.title}/>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    )
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**your main code problem is only type e.id is not working**

**try this**

{

```
       Array.isArray(allRecipes) ? allRecipes?.map((e) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Link to={"/home" + {e?.id}>
                            <Card title={e?.title}/>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                )
            }) : return <div> data is empty </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).